# form.serialize() is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am struck with the problem, I have page called view employee and when we click on that displaying all the employs, for each employee I have edit button and below is the respective page

```
echo "<form class="form-horizontal id="update_form" name="update_form" method="POST" action="update_employee_details.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <legend>Edit Employee details for '.$id.'</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_image">Employee Image</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" id="emp_image_preview">
                    <img id="blah" src="upload/default_pic.jpg" alt="Preview" width="100" height="100" />
                </div>
                <div> <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">
        </span><span class="fileupload-exists"></span>
                    <input type="file" id="emp_image" name="file" onChange="readURL(this);" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="flag_id" name="flag_id" value='.$id.'>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_id">Employee Id</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_id2" name="emp_id2" type="text" value="'.$id.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_fname">Firstname</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_fname" name="emp_fname" type="text" value="'.$fname.'" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_lname">Lastname</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_lname" name="emp_lname" type="text" value="'.$lname.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_username">Username</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_username" name="emp_username" type="text" value="'.$username.'" name="emp_username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_password">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_password" name="emp_password" type="password" value="'.$password.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_repassword">Re-Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_repassword" name="emp_repassword" type="password" value="'.$password.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_gender">Gender</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="form-control" id="emp_gender" name="emp_gender">
                <option value="'.$gender.'">'.$gender.'</option>
                <option value="">-select--</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_email">E-mail</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_email" name="emp_email" type="text" value="'.$email.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_contact">Contact no</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_contact" name="emp_contact" type="text" value="'.$contactno.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_dob">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge datepicker" id="emp_dob" name="emp_dob" value="'.$dateofbirth.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_id_type">Id Card Type</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="form-control" id="emp_id_type" name="emp_id_type" selected="'.$idcardtype.'">
                <option value="'.$idcardtype.'">'.$idcardtype.'</option>
                <option value="">--select--</option>
                <option value="Aadhar card">Aadhar Card</option>
                <option value="credit card issued by bank">credit Card issued by bank</option>
                <option value="Driving licence">Driving licence</option>
                <option value="Nationalize bank passbook">Nationalize bank passbook</option>
                <option value="Pan card">Pan card</option>
                <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
                <option value="Student Id Card">Student Id Card</option>
                <option value="Voters id card">Voters id card</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_id_number">Id Card Number</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_id_number" name="emp_id_number" type="text" value="'.$idcardno.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_per_address">Permanent Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="input-xlarge textarea" id="emp_per_address" style="width: 310px; height: 150px">'.$peraddress.'</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_temp_address">Temparary Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="input-xlarge textarea" id="emp_temp_address" style="width: 310px; height: 150px">'.$tempaddress.'</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_designation">Designation</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_designation" name="emp_designation" type="text" value="'.$designation.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_role">Role</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="form-control" id="emp_role" name="emp_role">
                <option value="administrator">Administrator</option>
                <option value="fulltime">Fulltime</option>
                <option value="parttime">Parttime</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_department">Department</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="form-control" id="emp_department" name="emp_department">
                <option value="'.$department.'">'.$department.'</option>
                <option value="">--select--</option>
                <option value="Accounts">Accounts</option>
                <option value="Event management">Event management</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
                <option value="Tele-caller">Tele-caller</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_joining_date">Date of Joining</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge datepicker" id="emp_joining_date" name="emp_joining_date" value="'.$dateofjoining.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_alloted_leaves">No of alloted leaves</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_alloted_leaves" name="emp_alloted_leaves" type="text" value="'.$allotedleaves.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_salary">Salary</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_salary" name="emp_salary" type="text" value="'.$salary.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_previous_company">Previous Company</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_previous_company" name="emp_previous_company" type="text" value="'.$salary.'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="emp_off_timing">Office Timing</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="emp_off_timing_in" name="emp_off_timing_in" type="text" value="'.$timing.'" placeholder="in time">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save_changes" name="btn_save_changes" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn" id="btn_cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>";
```

and my js part is here

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn_save_changes', function (event) {

    var formValues = $('#update_form').serialize();

    alert(formValues);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'view_edit_delete/update_employee_details.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formValues,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    }

    });

});
```

I am getting empty when I use alert :-( .I tried everything `var formValues= new FormData($(this)[0]);`
    but still no results

Comment: You could at least format your code, for convenience of people, trying to help you.

Comment: Is the top block of code what is returned by update_employee_details.php? Because it's going to throw syntax errors all over the place. You have an echo with a `"` and then a boat load of unescaped `"`s in your html.

Comment: Don't echo out a whole page (`echo "[way too much html  here]";`), only use php to echo out variables where needed (eg. `<p>Hi <?php echo $user; ?></p>`). And as for your current question: please give some more hints, it's a bit too vague what the problem is (and format your code please...).

Comment: That's not valid code: `echo "<form class="form-horizontal` See your quoting

Comment: ok I will try to put it in html and check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've missed (")
at

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="update_form"
```

after «form-horizontal»

in case of

```
 <form class="form-horizontal id="update_form"
```

ID of the form becomes « update_form»  (with leading space) and `$('#update_form')` founds nothing.

When you debug your applications do not hesitate to press F12 and use the Console to manually try simple parts of your code. Using the Console it is easy to find out that `$('#update_form')` does not find an element. And after that investigate why it happend.

Comment: Sorry guys it's my mistake . I couldn't able to find that error since I have written in echo . Thanks Naeel

Answer (score 1):

first of all please dont put your HTML code in php.

and then

```
<form class="form-horizontal
    <form class="form-horizontal"
```

close class tag

and for standard dont mix html code with php.

for designing use well format HTML code and to provide dynamicity put php value in html tags. its work easy and make code well understandable.

Comment: Please no more down votes . I am still learning php and I will rectify and won't repeat this kinda of problems again .Thanks

Comment: i am not down vote. i get this to see your code, and appreciate your attempt.

Answer (score -1):

Do: php inside html...
Don't: html inside php echo statement...
Don't simply use echo in php for html tags why because IDEs like netbeans wont show up error what ever you put up in php echo statement. It's not the best practice for coding. or if you really need just use php where you want it you use  "> instead of echo "  ..

Comment: Your suggestion is not useful in helping to answer this question